# Update component from select value ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is a select which gets ID's from an API,
then i have a table that displays data.

if i define a state like the example this.state = {value:23};
the table displays the data without problems from http://.../23

What i'm trying to achieve is that the table gets updated after change the select.
i can get the selected value by console.log( event.target.value); but i'm getting stuck trying to pass this value to:

< Table value={this.state.value} />

and re-rendering the table! any help is appreciated!

```js
class Planet extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 23};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event){
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    console.log(event.target.value);
}

handleSubmit(event){
    this.setState({value: this.state.value});
    //event.preventDefault();
}

render () {
    let planets = this.props.state.planets;
    let optionItems = planets.map((planet) =>
            <option key={planet.id}>{planet.id}</option>
        );

    return (
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
         <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="dropbox" >
            {optionItems}
         </select>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
         </form >
         <Table value={this.state.value} />
         </div>
    )
}
```

```js
export default class Table extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
  }


  fetchData() {
  const url = 'http://localhost:8000/sprints/';
  const value = this.props.value;
  var string = url+value;
  fetch(string)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((myJson) => this.setState(myJson));
}

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
  }

render() {
    return this.state.sprints ? (
      <div>
        <ResponseTable data={this.state.sprints} />
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div>
         Loading ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't have any problems with passing `props`. You should make additional request using [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle hook after your component is updated, but don't forget to check if value is changed.

Like this:

**Table component**

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.value !== this.props.value) {
        this.fetchData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either `componentWillReceiveProps(props)` inside `Table` class which will get called everytime you update state in parent component. Inside that method you can recall fetch method again

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops